# Form not registering on Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two forms on the profile page and when I submit them, it successfully submits the form but is not registering on the admin. What should I do? I've been building this app for over a month already but is stuck at 70%.

My models are:

```
class Translate(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=10000)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "translation"
        verbose_name_plural = "translations"

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

class Narrate(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=10000)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "narration"
        verbose_name_plural = "narrations"

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Now on my views.py, it's structured this way because it has 2 forms on one page. Is it better to used class based views on my situation or function based views?

```
class ProfilePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        add_narration = NarrateForm(self.request.GET or None)
        add_translation = TranslateForm(self.request.GET or None)
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['add_narration'] = add_narration
        context['add_translation'] = add_translation
        return self.render_to_response(context)

class NarrateFormView(FormView):
    form_class = NarrateForm
    template_name = 'profile.html'

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            add_narration = self.form_class(request.POST)
            add_translation = TranslateForm()
            if add_narration.is_valid():
                add_narration.save()
                return self.render_to_response(
                    self.get_context_data(
                        success=True
                    )
                )
            else:
                return self.render_to_response(
                    self.get_context_data(
                        add_narration=add_narration,
                    )
                )

def submittedView(request):
    return render(request, 'submission.html')

class TranslateFormView(FormView):
    form_class = TranslateForm
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        add_translation = self.form_class(request.POST)
        add_narration = NarrateForm()
        if add_translation.is_valid():
            add_translation.save()
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(
                    success=True
                )
            )
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(
                    add_translation=add_translation,
                )
            )

def submittedView(request):
    return render(request, 'submission.html')
```

And my forms.py are implemented this way.

```
class NarrateForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Narrate
    fields = [
        'title',
        'body',
    ]

class TranslateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Translate
        fields = [
            'title',
            'body',
        ]
```

Here's the form on the profile.html and the urls.py

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'submitted' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ add_narration }}
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Narration" class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-button light-blue mt-30">Submit Narration</button>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'submitted' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ add_narration }}
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Narration" class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-button light-blue mt-30">Submit Narration</button>
</form>
```

And here's the urls. I noticed that I did not include the views for my forms here

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('about/', AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('volunteers/', VolunteerView.as_view(), name='volunteers'),
    path('profile/', ProfilePageView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('submitted/', submittedView, name='submitted'),
]
```

Comment: Can you rephrase "not registering"? That has a specific meaning with Django, but its unclear whether that is relevant here.

Comment: You're showing a lot of views, so it's not clear which particular view is used when you submit your form. How do you know it's submitted successfully? If you set a breakpoint on the line `add_narration.save()` for example, do you hit that line, i.e. do you know for sure the form is being saved?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser What I mean is that when I submit the form, it's not showing on the admin.

Comment: @dirkgroten that's the problem, it doesn't save even if it has an add_narration.save()

Comment: But do know for sure the code at line `add_narration.save()` is executed? You're not answering my question.

Comment: @dirkgroten No.

Comment: Because presumably the form is not valid. Are you displaying form errors anywhere?

Comment: (And why do you have two views called `submittedView`?)

Comment: And thirdly, are you sure that your form is even being submitted to the NarrateFormView? Please show your profile.html and your urls.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman there are no errors. the form is submitted. on the cli, there are no errors. the problem is the form is not being saved on the admin.

Comment: If your form is not valid, there won't be any errors on the cli. You need to display the form errors in your template. All your code is valid and won't raise errors in the cli, but you need to check which code is running when you submit your form. Again: **Where are you submitting your form to? Which view?** By showing us your template (profile.html) and your urls.py we should be able to see what's going on.

Comment: @dirkgroten updated my quesiton

Comment: You're posting your form to the `submittedView` which does nothing else than render the submission.html template. Why do you expect your forms to be saved then? Why `action="{% url 'submitted' %}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add url patterns for the two views you have for each form, the `TranslateFormView` and the `NarrateFormView`.

And change your `action` attributes on each form to point to these two urls.

Comment: Alright. then I add {% if form.is_submitted %} <p>Thank you message</p> right?

Comment: with successful submission, the context variable is called `success` so you would need to use `{% if success %}`

Comment: {% if success %} thanks for submitting {% else %} try again right?